# _.intersectionWith does give correct result when objects compared order change

Tags: lodash

I am trying to use _.intersectionWith from lodash lib to find intersection element between two arrays of objects. This is not working.

```
var obj1 = [{'a':[],'b':'testobj'}]
var obj2 = [{'a':[],'b':'testobj'},{'a':[],'b':'testing'}]

_.intersectionWith(obj1, obj2)
```

expecting `[{'a':[],'b':'testobj'}]` but actual is `[]`

Comment: Did you try providing a comparator per https://lodash.com/docs#intersectionWith?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`_.intersectionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersectionWith) method expects a function that will compare the items. In your case, you can use [`_.isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual), that performs a deep comparison between two values to determine if they are equivalent:

```js
const obj1 = [{'a':[],'b':'testobj'}]
const obj2 = [{'a':[],'b':'testobj'},{'a':[],'b':'testing'}]

const result = _.intersectionWith(obj1, obj2, _.isEqual)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated already you are missing the `comparator` function. Same example is actually in the lodash [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersectionWith). In your case [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual) would do that deep comparison for you.

You can achieve the same exact result with [_.uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqBy) which is somewhat shorter:

```js
var obj1 = [{'a':[],'b':'testobj'}]
var obj2 = [{'a':[],'b':'testobj'},{'a':[],'b':'testing'}]

let result = _.uniqBy([...obj1, ...obj2], _.isEqual)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```